# terminal fringes and diff-hl

Tags: term, line-numbers, fringe, fringe-mode

I use [`diff-hl`](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl) to highlight changed lines. However it doesn't play well in terminal mode. I know that terminal Emacs doesn't support fringes, and it is better to use `diff-hl-margin-mode` instead, it works in terminal but margins are awful with `linum`.

GUI `diff-hl-margin-mode`:

[image]

...and the same situation in terminal. I tried [`nlinum`](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nlinum.html) instead, but with no luck. And also, i tried [`git-gutter`](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-git-gutter), but couldn't get live update to work, btw it uses margins to mark changed lines and it looks like on screenshot.

How do you handle this? Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

emacs-26 comes with a built-in line number mode, controlled by `display-line-numbers` which might combine better with other packages.